# Triangle with box shadow and not equal width

Tags: css, sass

I am looking to have a left arrow that is 40px by 20px with a `box-shadow`. I have tried

The single right border approach -- the dimensions work perfectly, but then there is a square box border:

```
.item {
  ...

  &::before {
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid #fff;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    height: 0;
    left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

and the double border approach -- box shadow works great, but the dimensions are incorrect since it needs to be a perfect square for the triangle to work:

```
.item {
  ...

  &::before {
    border: 20px solid black;
    border-color: transparent transparent #fff #fff;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 }
```

}

Is it possible to achieve with CSS or do I just need to a use an SVG?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter: drop-shadow` instead of `box-shadow`:

```
    filter: drop-shadow(-3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow